# Android custom view drawing

Tags: android, canvas, touch, android-bitmap

Android custom view drawing:
Screenshot:

[image]

This can't save the last trace, i want to redraw on a bitmap but the effect is not very good.

Screenshot:

[image]

code:

```
public class CustomView extends View {

private float sX, sY, eX, eY;

private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
private Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            eX = event.getX();
            eY = event.getY();
            canvas.drawLine(sX, sY, eX, eY, paint);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            sX = event.getX();
            sY = event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, getMatrix(), null);
}
}
```

Have you ever encountered the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should update the `sX` `sY` variable, when your finger is moving

1. ACTION_DOWN point is [100, 100] `sX = 100`, `sY = 100`
2. ACTION_MOVE now finger is locating at [130, 150] `eY = 130`, `eY = 150`
3. `invalidate()` so will trigger `draw()` draw line [100, 100] to [130, 150]
4. finger continue to move
5. ACTION_MOVE now the start is [130, 150] `sX = 130`, `sY = 150` **not ACTION_DOWN point value**
6. ACTION_MOVE now finger is locating at [160, 180]
7. `invalidate()` so will trigger `draw()` draw line [130, 150] to [160, 180]
8. continue do the same thing .....

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            eX = event.getX();
            eY = event.getY();
            invalidate()
            sX = eX;
            sY = eY;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            sX = event.getX();
            sY = event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            canvas.drawLine(sX, sY, eX, eY, paint);
            break;
    }
    //invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

i have not Run the code, but maybe you have understood what i mean.

**you should update both `startX` `startY`, and `endX` `endY`**

Comment: I understand what you mean, but my goal is to draw the bitmap only in the view's onDraw, without doing anything else, then you will only draw the line when you lift it up. What I want is to follow the finger and slide straight.Update

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, but I don't want to solve the problem in this way. My goal is to solve the problem with only the new canvas.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLhGH.png)

```
public class CustomView extends View {

private float sX, sY, eX, eY;

private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
private Bitmap bitmap;

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            eX = event.getX();
            eY = event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            sX = event.getX();
            sY = event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            canvas.drawLine(sX, sY, eX, eY, paint);
            break;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, getMatrix(), null);
    canvas.drawLine(sX, sY, eX, eY, paint);
}
}
```

or

```
public class CustomView extends View {

private Paint paint = new Paint();
private List<Path> cache = new ArrayList<>();
private Path currentPath;

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (currentPath != null) {
                currentPath.eX = event.getX();
                currentPath.eY = event.getY();
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            currentPath = new Path();
            currentPath.sX = event.getX();
            currentPath.sY = event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (currentPath != null) {
                cache.add(currentPath);
                currentPath = null;
            }
            break;

    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    for (Path path : cache) {
        canvas.drawLine(path.sX, path.sY, path.eX, path.eY, paint);
    }
    if (currentPath == null) return;
    canvas.drawLine(currentPath.sX, currentPath.sY, currentPath.eX, currentPath.eY, paint);
}

static class Path {
    float sX;
    float sY;
    float eX;
    float eY;
}
}
```